# PHP in MacOS Catalina throwing SIGILL when using PDO with SSL

Tags: php, pdo, macos-catalina

I'm on MacOS 10.15.1 (19B88). PHP scripts that connect to MySQL over SSL were working before the upgrade, now they're throwing SIGILL the moment `new PDO()` runs. Basic reproduceable example:

```
<?php

new PDO('mysql:', null, null, [
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT => 'foo',
]);
```

This is happening with PHP 7.2 and 7.3.11 installed via homebrew, as well as with PHP 7.3.9 which ships with MacOS (/usr/bin/php). There's no exception to catch or anything, the process immediately throws SIGILL.

Bash shows the error as: `Illegal instruction: 4`
Fish shows the error as: `fish: 'php test.php' terminated by signal SIGILL (Illegal instruction)`

I've added Terminal/iTerm/php binaries to "Full Disk Access" in the security preference pane in case it's related to the new disk access permissions, but that didn't make a difference. Maybe the issue is too specific for help, and I don't see others reporting this, but I'm grasping here.

Comment: from the php github "The SIGILL signal is sent to a process when it attempts to execute an illegal, malformed, unknown, or privileged instruction."... so the only thing i can think is that the script has not enough privilege tu run... is this a script or a webpage?

Comment: Running a script through terminal.

Comment: using sudo?....

Comment: No problems here on 7.3.9 built-in or 7.2.23 (MacPorts)

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. Tried sudo thinking it was maybe related to elevated restrictions in Catalina, no dice.